# Mahout: Visualizing cluster trough command line

Tags: hadoop, visualization, cluster-analysis, mahout

I am doing some experiments with clustering but now I want to visualize the data. Like in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Visualizing+Sample+Clusters , is there a way to run the classes with arguments that accept custom cluster data ? What is the best way to see cluster data?

The command i am using is: mvn -q exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.mahout.clustering.display.DisplayClustering

Thank you

PS: I am using Mahout 0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any realistic data that is visualizable in 2 dimensions (and I don't think these classes can do much more than that) will easily fit into main memory. And if I'm not mistaken, these classes *will* load all the data into your memory, because they are only for demonstration.

Then you may as well use any non-Hadoop tool such as [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) or WEKA or SciPy. Mahout really only pays off when you have more data than fits into your main memory. Otherwise, it will be a lot slower than a good single-host solution.

See e.g. [this G+ post](https://plus.google.com/101988970685633977359/posts/YkiexcjLcSc):

> **If your data is small enough to fit in main memory, don't run Hadoop.**

Comment: Thanks, have you found some examples on how to make the Mahout output "readable" to those tools?

Comment: Why would you? They can do clustering themselves, and are much faster than Mahout. So if your data fits into main memory, why cluster with Mahout then?

Comment: Exactly because of that, I've got 10 dimensions and 15gb per day to process, so it gets a bit heavy/costly to put it on memory